# setting a field in a class, does the original object not change the field?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how this works under the hood. I have a feeling i am overlooking this but I have this code.

```
newNode.setNextNode(root);
root = newNode;
return true;
```

**code for node class**

```
public class Node <T extends Comparable <T>> implements Comparable<T>{

    private Node nextNode = null;
    private T data;

    public Node(T data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean setNextNode(Node nextNode){
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
        return true;
    }

    public Node next(){
        return nextNode;
    }

    public T getData(){
        return data;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data.toString();
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(T o) {
        return getData().compareTo((T) nextNode.getData());
    }
}
```

root is now set to a field in my new node. 
when then do root = newNode. why when i do root.next does it not just give me back the root?

when I do the setter does it create a complete copy of the object? as I am aware when you make one object equal to another the reference refers to the same object. therefore it can change the original object.

if anyone could explain this would be great

Thank you

Comment: Can you share your class for root/newNode?

Comment: @RyanSayles added to the post

Comment: No, it's not creating a copy.  It assigns the reference that's passed in to the private member variable.  If you want a copy you'll have to write a copy constructor and call it.

Comment: so when I make it equal to the reference like i do on the call to the setNextNode, if i was to change something about the root ie make it point to a new object does that not change the nextNode field too? @duffymo

Comment: Yes it does.  That's why you should make copies of all mutable objects.  Only immutable objects can be safely assigned that way.